How can I use a relay to control an inverter from a Raspberry pi pico?
The inverter has a remote on/off port that can be used with an rj10 cable.
I connected an Rj9 cable (The same as Rj10/Rj22, 4p4c) to the port on the inverter, and stripped the other end to get access to the individual yellow and black wire.
Using this information, I saw that the yellow cable is Vdd and the black cable is GND. However, I am not sure if this pinout is really correct since as the Rj9 is used mostly for telephone cables and also other diagrams say a different pinout.
In my case I went with the first diagram and connected the yellow to the C terminal of an srd-05vdc-sl-c relay, and the black to the NC terminal of the relay. These wires were stripped and inserted into the relay. The relay's 5V VDD, GND, and Signal pins were connected to a raspberry pi's respective ports.
The micropython code is as follows:
import machine
from machine import Pin, I2C, PWM, ADC

relayPin = machine.Pin(16, Pin.OUT)

relayPin.value(0) # Turn the relay ON to turn the inverter OFF since we are using relay's NC

print("relay on")

utime.sleep(15)

relayPin.value(1)

print("relay off")# Turn the relay OFF to turn the inverter back ON

The print statements execute, and the light on the relay turns on and off, but the actual inverter does not turn off. Have I made a mistake in my wiring?
Here is a wiring diagram I made in Canva to see easier: https://www.canva.com/design/DAGCO3NiugQ/w1MAM4gu89nqCU_CKXeT0A/edit?utm_content=DAGCO3NiugQ&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton

This is not a Pi question. Whether you can control a relay from Pico would be but you have not provided any details.
